# Atheistisches Äquivalent von »Gott bewahre«?

Tags: phrase-request

*Gott bewahre* wird als ein Nebensatz verwendet, wenn der Sprechende hofft, dass das Genannte nicht auftritt:

> Und wenn er, *Gott bewahre,* tatsächlich krank wird ...

Gibt es dafür ein sprachlich elegantes Äquivalent ohne das Wort *Gott*?

Comment: *gottbewahre* (ich musste nachschauen - der Duden hält das tatsächlich für ein Adverb, das klein und zusammen geschrieben wird) ist an sich schon sehr *atheistisch* - Keiner denkt an einen Gott, wenn er dieses Wort benutzt

Comment: @IQV und Barth Zalewski: Wenn drei Punkte als Auslassungszeichen verwendet werden, die Platzhalter für ein Wort oder mehrere Wörter sind, müssen diese drei Punkte wie ein Wort behandelt werden, das heißt: In einem Satz muss davor ein Leerzeichen stehen! (Wenn damit ein Satz endet, muss aber kein weiterer Punkt angefügt werden um den Satz abzuschließen.) Richtig wäre also in Barths Frage »krank wird ...« (ich habe das so ausgebessert) und in IQVs Kommentar »mitnichten, ...« und natürlich ebenfalls »krank wird ...« (dort kann es leider nicht mehr korrigiert werden).

Comment: Suchst du eine atheistische Alternative oder nur eine, die nichts mit Religion zu tun hat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der neue österreichische Bundespräsident Alexander Van der Bellen ist Atheist, und er verwendet (wie viele andere Atheisten) diesen Ausdruck ebenfalls, so wie es in Österreich allgemein üblich ist, einander mit »Grüß Gott« zu grüßen, oder »Gott sei dank!« zu rufen, wenn eine kritische Situation glücklich ausgegangen ist. (Um genau zu sein: VdB sagt häufig »Gott behüte«, was aber genau dasselbe wie »Gott bewahre« bedeutet).

Auch wenn der Ausdruck einen eindeutig religiösen Ursprung hat, so wird dieser religiöse Hintergrund meist nicht mehr mitgedacht. Daher sollte man keine voreiligen Schlüsse ziehen, wenn man jemanden das sagen hört.

Aber natürlich kann man den zitierten Satz auch anders formulieren. Mit der Floskel »Gott bewahre« will der Sprecher ja ausdrücken, dass er wünsch und hofft, das geschilderte Ereignis möge nicht geschehen. Genau das leistet auch die Floskel »wie ich nicht hoffe«:

> Und wenn er, *wie ich nicht hoffe,* tatsächlich krank wird ...

Statt »wie« kann man auch »was« verwenden:

> Und wenn er, *was ich nicht hoffe,* tatsächlich krank wird ...

Answer (score 3):

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gottbewahre) definiert den Begriff als "abwehrende oder verneinende Beteuerung" und nennt als Synonyme "auf keinen Fall, bestimmt nicht, keinesfalls, mitnichten, ...". Da die aber hier nicht so richtig passen, würde ich etwas in der Art

> Und wenn er, was ich nicht hoffe, tatsächlich krank wird ...

vorschlagen.

Comment: Die Wendung wird so tatsächlich verwendet, was aber der Bedeutung von *hoffen*, nämlich etwas Positives oder Angenehmes erwarten, streng genommen widerspricht.

Comment: @guidot: Das passt aber zusammen mit der Tatsache, dass auch *hoffen* nicht auf die von dir beschriebene Weise verwendet wird.

Answer (score 2):

Further phrases that would be applicable in everyday communication:

> Und wenn er - was wir nicht hoffen wollen - tatsächlich krank wird...
>
> Und wenn er - Gott behüte! - tatsächlich krank wird...

(Well, okay, that's again with *Gott*...)

> Und wenn er - der Himmel sei davor! - tatsächlich krank wird...

(No *Gott* mentioned, but his/her supposed headquarters, so that's a metonymy)

> Und wenn er - es möge ihm erspart bleiben - tatsächlich krank wird...

The latter would be very rare, and it is a littly bit high-toned, but could well be used e.g. in a public address.

Answer (score 0):

Auf English würde man sagen: “perish the thought!”. Auf deutsch notfalls “möge es nicht geschehen!”

Comment: Klingt ein wenig literarisch/hochsprachlich, aber dennoch ein guter Vorschlag.